# C++ Clean String to int cast

Tags: c++, string, casting, int

As far as i know, the common way in c++ to cast a String into a int is to use sstream:

```
   std::string inputString = "12 34";
   std::istringstream istr(inputString);
   int i1, i2;
   istr >> i1 >> i2;
```

But if I want to make sure, that my code works for any input, the problem is to decide between the input of a string or 0:

```
   std::string inputString = "TEXT 0";
   std::istringstream istr(inputString);
   int i1, i2;
   istr >> i1 >> i2;
   cout << i1 <<"  !=  "<< i2 << endl;
```

I want to decide, if the user has inputed a String or a zero, in order to perform further manipulation.
Is there a **clean** way to decide this problem, without using lexical cast or atoi?
best gegards

Comment: At least to me, it's not clear exactly what decision you're making, or (especially) the criteria for the decision.

Comment: `if (!(istr >> i1 >> i2)) { /* something didn't extract */ }`

Comment: thx, that solution seems stable/clean to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an invalid default value:

```
#include<sstream>
#include<limits>
using std::numeric_limits;
int main(){
    std::string inputString = "TEXT 0"; 
    std::istringstream istr(inputString);
    int i1=numeric_limits<int>::min();
    int i2=numeric_limits<int>::min(); 
    std::string tmp;
    istr >> i1;
    if (i1 == numeric_limits<int>::min()) {
      // extraction failed
      i1 = 0;
      istr.clear(); // clear error flags to allow further extraction
      istr >> tmp; // consume the troublesome token
    }
    // same for i2
}
```

*Note*: The technique works if `numeric_limits<int>::min()` *cannot* be a valid input

Comment: Couldn't he use NaN as default value and keep min as valid input?

Comment: @dutt - What NaN do you have in mind for a C++ `int` variable?

Comment: Sorry, NaN is for float. Got things a bit mixed up.